# G++ cannot find cc1plus for some users

Tags: bash, g++

I am trying to run a PHP script to compile C code through a bash script for an online code submission server. When I run the bash script as root, it all works. When I run it as www-data, the user associated with the web server, it fails to find `cc1plus`, giving the error:

```
g++-5: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory.
```

I tried re-installing g++ and I have made sure that my gcc and g++ have the same version.

Comment: `cc1plus` belongs to `g++-5` package try reinstalling it, `sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++-5`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  Could the two users have different paths?

Comment: Not by default but it could be if user make custom modification to `.profile`, `.bashrc`...  try `sudo updatedb; locate cc1plus`

Comment: What do the commands `sudo -u www-data sh -c 'which g++-5'` and `sudo -u www-data sh -c 'g++-5 -print-prog-name=cc1plus'` say?

Comment: steeldriver: both of those commands return /usr/bin/g++-5.

sneetsher: after the updatedb, the locate command gave /usr/bin/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus

Also after the updatedb, the same error happens when I run the script

Comment: The output has been pasted: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17971924/

It is indeed /lib and not /bin, and it sounds like that might be an issue?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky , my mistake I meant `p="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1plus"; while [ "$p" != "/" ] ; do ls -dl $p ; p=$(dirname $p); done`

Comment: The output from that is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17972462/

Comment: Check the directory permissions, as well as the permissions on `cc1plus`. You could use my `pathlld` tool, http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17976629/

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky, Could you try with verbose flag `g++ -v ...`

Comment: Hi,  that gives the following: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/17981149/

Sorry for the format, this is the output from the web server itself

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky, Could you check `env` but I don't think you have custom path if you didn't do that yourself. You try setting path manually: `COMPILER_PATH="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/" g++ ...` if didn't work `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/" g++ ...`

Comment: Hi,  when trying that, it tells me that there is no such file or directly.  It will do that even if I just restrict it to /usr/lib, even though I can cd into that directory.  Also, if I echo $COMPILER_PATH, I get a blank line.  I'm sorry, I'm not yet familiar enough with linux to understand what that means...Also, env does not have a variable COMPILER_PATH, though I could make one?

Comment: I have in fact solved the problem.  It turns out that there needed to be a symbolic link to cc1plus, since it was in a strange directory.

Comment: It would be great if you could post an answer to this to help others in the same situation :)